# Avoiding a loop

Tags: jquery

Is there any way to do something like this to avoid having to do `.each` or a `for` loop?

```
$('.backstretch-frame').backstretch( function(){ return $(this).data('img'); } );
```

Basically trying to pull the contents of the attribute for that particular object in the collection for instantiation.

Comment: It's not very clear what your intended result is.  Are you looking for an array of strings which are the `img` data attribute of each `.backstrecth-frame`?

Comment: In a nutshell, I'd like to apply `backstretch()` to all instances of `.backstretch-frame` using an inline getter instead of having to set up a for loop or using jQuery's `.each()` functionality.

Comment: Sorry, but `.data` can only return one value for one element. Why don't you want to use `.each`? This is exactly the sort of thing you need it for.

Comment: What is `backstretch`?  Why don't you want to use a loop?  There's nothing wrong with `.each`; jQuery uses it internally when you do something like `$('.multi').attr('abc', 123);`!

Comment: Thanks for the help guys - I think I'll just do the each loop. I don't think I was putting my question correctly, nbd.

Answer (score 1):

Like it or not, if you want to get ALL the `.data('img')` values for each instance of `.backstretch-frame`, you'll need an `.each` loop:

```
var temp_array = [];
$('.backstretch-frame').each(function() {
    var t = $(this).backstretch(function() { 
        return $(this).data('img');
    });
    temp_array.push(t);
});
// now temp_array contains all the values of .data('img'), in order
```